Sequelize associations with multi-tenant (schemas) solution
I'm rather new to backend development, so bear with me.
I have a 'partners' table in the 'public' schema and each partner has their own schema like 'partner_1', 'partner_2', etc...
Their schemas contain tables like customers, orders, items, addresses, etc...
The problem is with associations because they can't have the same name. When I try to set up the associations for each partner, the alias names conflict. In the following case, for example, I would expect it to work because the aliases reference different schemas, but it obviously doesn't and says that I can't have the same alias for multiple relations:
Customer.schema(schema).hasMany(CustomerAddress.schema(schema), {
    as: "addresses",
    foreignKey: "customer_id",
    onDelete: "CASCADE"
});
Customer.schema(schema).hasMany(Order.schema(schema), {
    as: "orders",
    foreignKey: "customer_id",
    onDelete: "CASCADE"
});
Customer.schema(schema).hasMany(Item.schema(schema), {
    as: "items",
    foreignKey: "customer_id",
    onDelete: "CASCADE"
});

I know this can be avoided by using some frameworks and graphql and whatnot, but is there no native way in sequelize to make the relations have this same name?
I also know I could add the 'schema' name in the aliases, so they would be: ${schema}_addressess and such, but then I would also have to transform every query response with 'include', which doesn't sound like a good and nice solution either.
If someone has a clean solution to this, that would be awesome.
I have tried using scope but later realized it wasn't exactly for the purpose I wanted to use it for.
I have also tried to include the schema name in the associations like I stated earlier, but it would require response transformations that feel totally unnecessary.
I would like a clean and simple solution if at all possible.

Did you look at the possibility to have a separate connection for each partner? That way you can register the same models and associations in each Sequelize connection (I'm not 100% sure it will work but it's worth to try it)

@Anatoly I had thought about it and had seen some examples while looking for an answer, but it felt like a bad solution. I have doubts about how the connection pooling and all that would be managed properly if each partner had a separate connection. It just feels/sounds like bad design to me, not sure if that's true.

The other wasy is to register models and associations with different names. maybe to use schemes as prefixes in their names.
